# Retornar texto en plpgsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, funciones, plpgsql

estoy haciendo un ejercicio para clase en el que me piden lo siguiente:

> Cree una función que devuelva un texto con un lista de las notas de un
>   alumno indicado por parámetro. El parámetro de entrada es obligatorio.
>   Hay que devolver null si el parámetro es null. No debe utilizarse
>   cursos, sino utilizar FOR ... IN SELECT
>
> Hay Generar la excepción 'internal_error' si el alumno no existe,
>   capturar esta excepción y mostrar una notificación (NOTICE) indicando
>   el mensaje Alumno no encontrado '
>
> Hay que devolver un texto diferente si el alumno no tiene ninguna
>   nota. También hay que utilizar los caracteres de escape necesarios
>   para dar formato al listado (saltos de línea, tabulaciones, etc ...)

Ejemplos:

```
 escuela => SELECT notes_alumne (1);
           notes_alumne
 ----------------------------------   
 Las notas del alumno Alex son:   
 M10 09:50   
 M07 08:50




 escuela => SELECT notes_alumne (3);
           notes_alumne
 ------------------------------   
 El alumno Anna no tiene ninguna nota
```

El problema que tengo, es que no se cómo hacer que una función retorne texto, y mucho menos, texto organizado en forma de lista, todo lo otro lo tengo hecho ya, sólo me falta esto, el poder plasmar el texto, alguien puede echarme un cable? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Muéstranos el cuerpo de la función como la tienes hasta ahora. Desde el `CREATE FUNCTION` en adelante. En segundo lugar, por favor muéstranos cómo debiera verse la salida. Dices que quieres retornar texto, ¿Texto con saltos de línea?  ¿Estás seguro que no quieres retornar un conjunto de filas?

Comment: Ok, ahora voy a ver si la cuelgo y tal, y si, la salida de texto tendría que ser con saltos de línia, no pide retornar filas